# The proving of Bourbaki Witt theorem and the Axiom of Choice

Tags: set-theory

The Bourbaki Witt theorem states that:
Let $ A $ be a nonempty partially ordered and strictly inductively
ordered set. Let $ f : A \rightarrow A $ be an increasing mapping/ inflationary mapping. Then there
exists an element $ x_0 \in A $ such that $ f(x_0) = x_0 $.

The reference that I use are

[1] https://dis.ijs.si/France/notes/Lang--Bourbaki-Witt--ORIGINAL.pdf
[2] https://dis.ijs.si/France/notes/Lang--Bourbaki-Witt.pdf
[3] http://athena.nitc.ac.in/~kmurali/Courses/Logic2016/zornleader.pdf
[4] https://www.math.bgu.ac.il/~ilan/topology/Zorn.pdf

In the proof of the Bourbaki Witt theorem, to show the set $ M_c $ is
admissible [1], most literature defines an element $ c \in M $ to be
*good/normal/extremal* if for all $ x \in M $, if $ x < c $ then 
$ f(x) \leq c $.

Also the Axiom of Choice is not needed to prove the Bourbaki Witt theorem.

**Question 1**: What is the backstory for being good/normal/extremal? 
I can see how if an element $ c $ is good/normal/extremal, then $ M_c $ is admissible so that given any $ x \in M $, either $ x \leq c $ or $ f(c) \leq x. $ What bothers me is that the element $ c $ is introduced out of thin air, if you will.

With this good point $ c $, the theorem is proven. I understand the proof.

**Question 2**: How is the AC not needed? Is it because if we identify all the chains
\begin{equation*}
   a \leq \dotsb \leq x 
\end{equation*}
then by hypothesis it has a least upper bound, and we can take the least upper
bound to be $ f(x) $? Here AC is not needed because we know the element that
succeeds $ x $ is $ f(x) $, the least upper bound of the chain?

**Question 3**: If there is an element $ c \in M $ such that $ x < c $ for all
$ x \in M $ then is $ f(x) $ is going to be always $ \leq c $ ? And if $ c $ covers $ x $ then $ f(x) \leq c $ always?

We then define such $ c $ to be normal/extremal?

What if there is no $ c $ ? Suppose $ x < c < f(x) $. Where is the contradiction?

**Question 4**: In [4] the author define such element $ c $ as a good point 
if whenever $ x < c $, we have $ f(x) \leq c $ (that is, we can't use 
$ f $ to "skip over" $ c $, or to get a point which is not comparable to 
$ c $).

I do not follow the bit where "is skip over and not comparable" because I have always thought $ f(x) $ is always as big as $ x $?

Comment: I don't understand Question 2.  Is there some specific step of the proof that you think should use the axiom of choice?  Or are you asking what is different about this result as opposed to Zorn's lemma that lets you prove it without choice?

Comment: In any case, if your goal is just to understand a proof of the Bourbaki-Witt theorem, the proof you are looking at is about the most opaque, difficult proof there is because it takes great pains to avoid making any use of well-ordered sets.  There is a very easy proof on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourbaki%E2%80%93Witt_theorem#Proof_of_the_theorem), if you're not afraid of using transfinite recursion.

Comment: This is the bit I do not understand "what is different about this result as opposed to Zorn's lemma that lets you prove it without choice".

I am also trying to avoid using the transfinite recursion.